# resource.rc: No such file or directory

Tags: codeblocks, wxwidgets

I'm setting CodeBlocks with wxWidgets, but enountered problems when compile an empty project:

```
resource.rc: No such file or directory
```

However, when I creat win32GUI project instead of wxWidgets, I could compile and run an empty GUI.

1. I installed CodeBlocks 17.12 on the path (D:\GreenSoft\CodeBlocks)
2. Add the “D:\GreenSoft\CodeBlocks\MinGW\bin” to the path environment variable.
3. Download the wxWidgets3.1.2 source code to “D:\GreenSoft\wxWidgets\wxWidgets312\”
4. cd to “D:\GreenSoft\wxWidgets\wxWidgets312\build\msw”, and run command:

   mingw32-make -f makefile.gcc BUILD=release SHARED=1 MONOLITHIC=1 UNICODE=1 CXXFLAGS=-fno-keep-inline-dllexport
5. After compile finished, I run the OpenBlocks and add a project wxWidget with several options:

   wxWidgets 3.1.*

   Project Title: App

   Prefered GUI builder: wxSmith

   Application type: frame-based

   wxWidgets location: D:\GreenSoft\wxWidgets\wxWidgets312

   Compiler: GUN GCC compiler

   Create Debug…

   Create Release…

   With three wxWidgets Library settings checked only
6. Then an empty GUI panel appeared in CodeBlocks.
7. I do nothing but click the compile button, and error appeared:

It says that

`gcc: error: D:QMDownloadrmdCsrrresource.rc: No such file or directory`

But I checked that the file D:\QMDownload\rmdCs\App\resource.rc exist , and its textcontent is:
aaaa ICON "wx/msw/std.ico"

## include "wx/msw/wx.rc"

I have found a post with the same issue and make sure that no blank space and special character exist in all the paths, but the problem still exist.

```
-------------- Build: Debug in App (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

windres.exe -ID:\GreenSoft\wxWidgets\wxWidgets312\include -ID:\GreenSoft\wxWidgets\wxWidgets312\lib\gcc_dll\mswu  -J rc -O coff -i D:\QMDownload\rmdCs\App\resource.rc -o obj\Debug\resource.res
x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++.exe -LD:\GreenSoft\wxWidgets\wxWidgets312\lib\gcc_dll -o bin\Debug\App.exe obj\Debug\AppApp.o obj\Debug\AppMain.o  obj\Debug\resource.res -mthreads  -lwxmsw31u -mwindows
gcc: error: D:QMDownloadrmdCsAppresource.rc: No such file or directory
gcc: warning: '-x c' after last input file has no effect
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
windres: preprocessing failed.
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
2 error(s), 1 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
```

Comment: A resource file does in Windows several tasks: Icons names, manifest, etc. Put it in the same directory as your .cpp files. Don't forget to tell C::B where to find headers and libraries.

Comment: After two days of struggle, all the reason is the Toolchain Executables. I finally found that it was cygwin's path!

After I change to D:\GreenSoft\CodeBlocks\MinGW, it compiles ok now!

I think the problem take place at the install step: codeblocks detect everywhere on your PC to find a existing gcc, and let you choose one as your favorite. It even forgot that the installer is already bundled with a minGW!, and it does not show where the detected gcc are located! So if you simply confirm one and forget it, it will abandon the bundled minGW.